# Having trouble with my 3rd Display

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Alright so I have 3 monitors. I just got a new monitor today and disconnected my old 3rd one since the newest one I got today is better. As I hook it up, it doesn't wanna pick up my PC. It goes through HDMI, on the Motherboard as the 2 spots on my GPU are taken up by one HDMI and one DVI port. I'm not sure why it's not working since it was just working on the old one with no problems. I've look in device manager, it's not picking it up in there, i've looked in the Display settings in the control panel, i've rebooted, nothing. Any help?

Comment: what happens if it's the only one connected?

Comment: It doesn't pick it up.

Comment: Then it's probably the monitor that is faulty.

Comment: possibly - or it doesn't like the gable. Try it with another HDMI, or the DVI instead. There's always the possibility it wants to see HDMI 1.4 & the cable is only 1.2

Comment: It shouldn't be a faulty monitor when it works perfectly fine on my PS3 actually.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try connecting the monitor to different ports on the GPU where a known monitor is connected to, and see if it works. Try HDMI, DVI, and VGA connections. Try booting to your PCs BIOS, as Windows might not recognise the monitor but the mobo might.

If it doesn't work, try with a different computer with a known working GPU. If that still doesnt work, the monitor may be faulty.

Comment: I'll be trying this here soon.